# Tracking topic size and consumer lag with kafka 0.8.2.0

Tags: python, apache-kafka

Since kafka 0.8.2.0 it seems to have gotten awfully hard to track consumer lag and topic sizes

How do you track offsets (topic size) and lag in kafka? Do you increment a counter somewhere when your producer inserts a message and increment another counter when your consumer acknowledges a message?

I'm using [airbnb's kafka-statsd-metrics2](https://github.com/airbnb/kafka-statsd-metrics2) - But all the metrics regarding topic size is always `0` for some reason, it may be a bug report for them, but how do you do it?

Our consumers and producers are written in python using [kafka-python](https://github.com/mumrah/kafka-python), they state they don't support the ConsumerCoordinator offset APIs, so I've put together a solution querying zookeeper and sending those metrics to statsd instance (seems very awkward), but I'm still missing the topic size metric.

We're using collectd to gather system metrics, I have NO experience with JMX and configuring it in collectd seems pretty convoluted, I've tried a few times, so I've found a few ways not to do it.

If you have any input I'd love to hear it, even if it is: "This belongs on  x stackexchange-site"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you could use `HighwaterMarkOffset` from the `FetchResponse`. This way you will know what is the offset in the end of partition and will be able to compare it with your current acked offset or offset of the last message in this `FetchResponse` for example.

Details [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-FetchResponse)

Comment: I'm marking your answer as my answered one as you got here first, and it's correct as well. I ended up creating a program that tracks our consumers offsets from Zookeeper, as that is what kafka-python is still using.
The good thing about this solution is that it's easy to pipe the results into our graphite setup :)
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using https://github.com/quantifind/KafkaOffsetMonitor for monitoring the consumer lag. It works well for 0.8.2.0

Comment: It's very odd.
I've had that installed ever since before 0.8.2.0, but it never worked after I upgraded, but I just thought what the hell and tried it again, and now it works beautifully without any updates...

Comment: The KafkaOffsetMonitor doesn't seem to work with simple consumers as it tries to retrieve partitions owners from zookeeper which appears to only be set by high level consumers. I think... ymmv

Answer (score 0):

here is the code snippet, make sure to run this in active controller.
BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS is active controller IP.

```
client = KafkaAdminClient(bootstrap_servers=BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS, request_timeout_ms=300)
      list_groups_request  = client.list_consumer_groups()

      for group in list_groups_request:
        if group[1] == 'consumer':
          list_mebers_in_groups = client.describe_consumer_groups([group[0]])
          (error_code, group_id, state, protocol_type, protocol, members) = list_mebers_in_groups[0]

          if len(members) !=0:
            for member in members:
              (member_id, client_id, client_host, member_metadata, member_assignment) = member
              member_topics_assignment = []
              for (topic, partitions) in MemberAssignment.decode(member_assignment).assignment:
                member_topics_assignment.append(topic)

              for topic in member_topics_assignment:
                consumer = KafkaConsumer(
                          bootstrap_servers=BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS,
                          group_id=group[0],
                          enable_auto_commit=False
                          )
                consumer.topics()

                for p in consumer.partitions_for_topic(topic):
                  tp = TopicPartition(topic, p)
                  consumer.assign([tp])
                  committed = consumer.committed(tp)
                  consumer.seek_to_end(tp)
                  last_offset = consumer.position(tp)
                  if last_offset != None and committed != None:
                    lag = last_offset - committed
                    print "group: {} topic:{} partition: {} lag: {}".format(group[0], topic, p, lag)
```